How to draw an irregular shape made of lines, arcs and splines?
What is the most straight forward way to draw a irregular shape made of lines and arc and spline, as shown in the screenshot?
Thanks for your help.


Are you talking about a bezier curve or about a mesh? You can also convert a bezier to a mesh afterwards...

Hi, I’m coming from SolidWorks, where all extrusions (Blender equivalent would be a face extrusion) start with a “sketch” where you can draw any shape using lines, arcs and splines and then extrude the sketch (extrude face in blender). I’m just looking for the closest/quickest equivalent to drawing the shape in the screenshot, which was done in SolidWorks, but to be able to do it in Blender. Thanks

Maybe the best is to use a bezier curve, then right click > Convert to > Mesh in Object mode, fill and extrude?

Ok sounds like a good place to start, thanks for the tip.

Blender is not a CAD software, other than bezier curves it doesn't have the concept of lines, circles or arcs. Maybe you should look into FreeCAD

I’m interested in the animation abilities of Blender, mainly using the models I make in SolidWorks and import into Blender.

For shapes like this i would draw this as a vector-file, save as a SVG and import that into Blender.
